# How can I link javascript files to my html like ajax does for Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to link a few javascript files to my HTML index file. I have used this for linking Jquery a few times:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

BUT how do I upload my own .js files to ajax or another library if ajax won't allow me?

Comment: This is the link to the slider I am trying to use:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/02/26/elastic-content-slider/

AND this is the Github link:
https://github.com/codrops/Blueprint-ElasticContentSlider

Comment: You just upload them the same way you upload any other file to your website. What's the problem?

Comment: save file + FTP to server == done!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload your files to `https://ajax`.... This is a Google server that acts as a global Content Delivery Network (CDN). A CDN is used to share common files (like jquery and jqueryUI) for all websites. The aim of CDN is to increase the chances of the file being cached and to reduce overall page traffic.

For example, if you visit Site A which uses a CDN, the jquery file will get cached. When you visit Site B that uses the same CDN, the jquery file does not need to be downloaded because it has already been cached on your local drive. This speeds up the loading of all websites that use the CDN.

For your elastic content slider, because it is not common enough to be placed in the CDN, you have to put the file on the same web-server as the rest of your pages. This is typically done using FTP.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. I uploaded the files to my domain.com account. Not sure if it is working because i'm using squarespace's code injection feature. If you are familiar with this platform, should I be putting these src links in the header or the footer?

Comment: @mydoghoward if you are wrapping your JS code in `document.ready` handlers, it doesn't matter where you put your src links.

Comment: @mydoghoward you should be able to tell if the code injection is working by using the network tab of the developer tools - you should be able to see your js files being loaded

Comment: I am using squarespace 7. I don't think it has a a developer tab. Just a "Custom CSS" and "Code Injection" and if I want to use "Developer Mode" my site wont be updated by squarespace. But here is the element I want to implement: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/02/26/elastic-content-slider/

Comment: @mydoghoward I meant the browser's developer tools (IE, chrome) :)